# Event Grid delivery to Service Bus with Session Id

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-eventgrid

As far as I know, event grid doesn't guarantee order in message delivery. But for Service Bus handler, I saw that we can specify a SessionId header for the message.
Will the messages come to service bus in order if we specify the session id?
Otherwise what's the point of enabling Session in service bus if the messages don't even come in order in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions in Service Bus allow messages to be processed serially by one client when receiving them, unlike the default behavior where multiple messages could be processed simultaneously.

While the order of messages are not guaranteed by Event Grid, whatever their order is when inserted into Service Bus will be guaranteed.